# Are Java literals really constant?

Tags: java

I see/hear people talking about literals as constants, but are they really constants?

I think of final as a constant:

```
 final constantNumber = 10;
```

E.g. in the literal below, I am able to change the value.

```
int testNumber = 10;
System.out.println(testNumber);
testNumber = 20;
System.out.println(testNumber);
```

Comment: The literal `"SomeString"` cannot change. In that sense, it is a constant.

Comment: In your example, why didn't you use `final constantNumber = 10;`?  Seems like a strawman argument or a non sequitur

Comment: The `literals` in this case would both be 10 and 20. You are just changing what value the variable holds. If the literals were not constant, you could assign `10` a different value.

Comment: The value "10" cannot change, it's "10". You've changed a *variable's* value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your example

```
int testNumber = 10;
```

`10` is the literal, not `testNumber`.  Yes, it is a constant.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Of course 10 is still 10, if i change the variables value to 20, the number 10 that the variable previously held is still 10, and 10 is still 10, but whats the point in stating that?

I feel i must be missing something crucial in my understanding. Is that really all there is to it?

Comment: @Xerphiel You may have heard or read someone mention that literals are constants in Java because this was not always the case in every programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those literals are constant.

[According to the wiki defenition:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming))

> literal is a notation for representing a fixed value in source code.
>   In contrast to literals, variables or constants are symbols that can take on one of a class of fixed values, the constant being constrained not to change. Literals are often used to initialize variables.

for example, in the following, 1 is a literal and the three letter string in `"cat"` is a literal:

```
 int a = 1;
 String s = "cat";
```

Here, `1` is literal, where as `a` is variable.

Comment: By this definition, "literal" is not a "constant", because a constant is a "symbol that can take on one of a class of fixed values", while a literal is a "fixed value".